# Can I consume a Web API as you would consume the contract of a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, azure

**Description:**

I have an client app consuming a WCF service, both runing on .NET Core and hosted as web apps in Azure.
The client has access to an interface that the service implements as its DataContract.
Currently I consume the service via creating a ChannelFactory based on an DataContract of the WCF service.

Because lots of reasons I'd like to move away from WCF.
My first idea was to convert the WCF service to a Web API and implement something like OpenAPI (Swagger) and from there consume the API via generated docs.
However I can't really find anything similar to the way you would consume a WCF contract and then be able to call upon its methods.

**Question:**

Is it possible o use a shared interface between the consumer and a Web API in a way that enables me to call upon the methods (routes) in that interface? Be it using OpenAPI (Swagger) or any other framework/lib/or otherwise.

Please let me know if anything is unclear and I'll add info, I'm aware its a somewhat broad question.

Comment: Swagger can generate the client proxies for a WebAPI service (in the same way Visual Studio generates client proxies for WCF) if a Swagger spec has been authored first (much like WSDL)

Comment: I understand you can generate a proxy from Swagger but I feel like it will add a layer of management and upkeep to rewrite the spec for every change/add/removal or methods to the REST service. Is there any way to automatically generate this proxy based on the controller/actions or would I have to rewrite the spec by hand?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Clever programmers can automatically generate the YAML from an existing code-first API (in exactly the same way Visual Studio generates WSDL from code-first).   Sounds like you want to bypass Swagger entirely